# Why mysql cmd wrapped with `nohup` and `&` still got `Terminal close -- query aborted` when I close terminal?

Tags: mysql, shell, nohup

This is my command to import sql file into mysql 5.7.33, the sql has 10M lines so take some time to run:

`nohup mysql -D bi -e "SET autocommit=0; SOURCE bi-6.sql; COMMIT;" &`

I closed terminal after run this cmd, When I go back later, I saw `Terminal close -- query aborted` in nohup.out, and db is not fully imported, Why? I believe process is aborted when I close terminal.

I originally thought it should run in background until importing finish like normally when I run Python / Java program.

Comment: are you by any chance lucky with this question?.. I am also facing similar situation

Comment: I had keep Terminal open to wait for its finishing.